# git - resolving conflict with rebase vs merge

Tags: git

So where i work merges is frowned on and not really permitted. Team wants to use git rebase to maintain a single flow of the history and make it look linear.  they dont want to see merge commits.  but i came into a situation today and didn't know how to solve it. i was working on a feature branch called featureBranchA and i stashed my changes and did git pull origin develop to get changes from develop.  the changes came but there was a conflict (even after the stash !!). it says the following:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): myapp/src/main/java/com/myCompany/app/rubberBands/crayons/CrayonMarker.kt deleted in 258dcbfccba83025cd0c3e1e22212e980a481a and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of myapp/src/main/java/com/myCompany/app/rubberBands/crayons/CrayonMarker.kt left in tree.
```

so clearly i need to fix this conflict to move on. so i did the following commands as it looks just like some file reference needs to be updated (the CrayonMarker.kt file had been deleted but someone my git thought it was still there):

```
git add .
git commit -m "merging to resolve conflicts"
git stash pop
```

and i was back in business but my team was not happy as it 'merged' changes . they want rebase only.  how could i have done this differently next time.  **after i fix the conflict** do i just run:

```
git rebase develop
```

what do i do after that ? commit changes ?

Comment: It depends; in your current scenario imho merge was the best option. https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Comment: yah i read this.  but merging is not permitted here.  i want to know how it can be done with rebase then.

Comment: You should talk with them....merge is a non destructive operation....

Comment: all they care about it keeping the history pretty. i spoke with them.

Comment: Merging is not permitted? Why?

Comment: I told them it's destructive. They said they want the history to be completely linear so they can see commits easier.

Comment: You might point out to your team that `git rebase` works by invoking `git cherry-pick` repeatedly, and each cherry-pick is, internally, a merge. :-) That probably will convince no one, unfortunately. They need to learn when merges are good, because sometimes merges *are* good. A rebase-oriented work-flow is fine, but there is no one-size-fits-all always-right-always-best answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the git docs:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":
>
> ```
>       A---B---C topic
>      /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> From this point, the result of either of the following commands:
>
> ```
> git rebase master
> git rebase master topic
> ```
>
> would be:
>
> ```
>               A'--B'--C' topic
>              /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```

It looks like a simple rebase from your `develop` branch could have solved this.

Comment: My question was after I do git rebase master do I need to commit the change and push it to master ?

Comment: Locally your branch should be branched off of the most recent develop commit. What you do from there is up to you (keep working without pushing, push to develop, push your branch and make a pull-request, etc).